# Developing a themed layout using rgba css property, not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem while creating a css driven themed layout for a site. The requirement is that a user will select a primary and secondary color for his customized theme. The are blocks in the page which are to be rendered with some opacity (or alpha value) above which a gradient image will be rendered. The problem with using opacity css property is that all child elements also inherit the opacity value which isn't what we want. On the other hand, using the rgba property has compatibility issues with IE. Which approach should I take ?

```
/* HTML */
  <div class="someClass">
       Page Title
 </div>

/* CSS */ 
.someClass{

  border-top:10px solid #b59a47;
  border-bottom:5px solid #f4e196;
  background-image: url(../../images/contentHeader-bg.png);
  background-color: rgba(244,225,150,0.2);
}
```

Comment: You need to use an filter for IE8 and below: http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/.

Comment: This is not what I want and I have already read this before posting this question. looking some good approach.

Comment: This is a good approach. You only have 2 choices in IE a png background image or the filter thing. There a re no other choices. This article shows you pros and cons of both: http://leaverou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all browsers support RGBa, so if the design permits, you should declare a "fallback" color. This color will be most likely be solid (fully opaque). Not declaring a fallback means no color will be applied in browsers that don't support it. This fallback does fail in some really old browsers.

```
div {
   background: rgb(200, 54, 54); /* The Fallback */
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
}
```

Do be aware of [this bug](http://css-tricks.com/5376-ie-background-rgb-bug/) though, related to not using shorthand in IE 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting no opacity to all child elements separately (if the problem is that they inherit the opacity value)?

```
.contentHeader {
   opacity:0.2;
   filter: alpha(opacity=20); /*for IE6-8*/
}
.contentHeader * {
   opacity:1;
   filter: alpha(opacity=100); /*for IE6-8*/
}
```

If it does not work in some browsers try to add `!important` for child styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it using the gradient filter where you can use rgba colors and just set same color for start and end:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000050,endColorstr=#99000050);
```